# Error : Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined

Tags: biblatex, miktex, compiling, input-encodings

I was adding references to my `.bib` file and everything was just working fine. I came acroos a document http://www.staffs.ac.uk/schools/business/resits/postgrad/InternationalSupplyChainMgmtIKEACaseStudy.pdf which is causing me the problem.

I am using JabRef to maintain my bib file. I did enter the document as a `techreport`. I `copied` the title `Written Examination Stimulus Material Case Study – IKEA` in the title section and `Industry supply chain management system` When I tried to execute my `main.tex` file, I get the error `! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined`. Well I did not understand what was happening, so I deleted the entry from `JabRef` and tried to re-execute removing the citation from `.tex` doc. But strange thing is I still get the error:

```
    ! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.206 \end
          {document}
You need to provide a definition with \DeclareInputText 
or \DeclareInputMath before using this key.


Overfull \hbox (17.45633pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 206--206
[]\OT1/lmr/m/it/12 Written Ex-am-i-na-tion Stim-u-lus Ma-te-rial Case Study  IK
EA\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 . Case Study BSB20123-
 []

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 206.
[26

]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 206.

("C:\path\main.aux")
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 206.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 206.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `main.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 14F03B1DF8016DE367A0F2F217A228DD;1969.
```

One observation in this error log is that, even though I removed the citation and entry from my `.bib` file it saying that :

```
Overfull \hbox (17.45633pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 206--206
    []\OT1/lmr/m/it/12 Written Ex-am-i-na-tion Stim-u-lus Ma-te-rial Case Study  IK
    EA\OT1/lmr/m/n/12 . Case Study BSB20123-
     []
```

But this title does not exist either in my `.tex` or my  `.bib`. Where is it reading this title from and what could be the possible solution to fix this?

I am using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` package.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The main information is missing, that is the error line. Try changing `Case Study – IKEA` into `Case Study -- IKEA` (that is, changing the `–` character into two hyphens).

Comment: @egreg Well I do not have this entry anymore in my ``.bib`` file. So, it should not show that at all. But I don't know where is it actually reading this.

Comment: A minimal example showing the error is needed.

Comment: @egreg  Well you can find the current ``.bib`` file here http://codepaste.net/nzw2f3  As you can see, I do not have the entry that the error is talking about.

Comment: You should at least add some lines of the log file before the one you started with.

Comment: Have you deleted all your LaTeX temporary files?

Comment: @MarkBirtwistle No. Sorry, may I know where I can find these files.

Comment: @egreg I have only current log file **main.log**. What do you mean by **before the one you started with.**? Thanks

Comment: @Sangamesh, they'll be in the same directory as your .tex file. LaTeX creates a number of such files as it compiles a document, with endings such as .aux, .bbl, .bcf, .blg etc. You can safely delete anything which doesn't end in .tex or .bib. If you have an editor such as TeXWorks, there will probably be a facility to do this for you.

Comment: @MarkBirtwistle Yesss. That's right. Deleting those files did solve the problem. But still I have a question like, which file among all could have caused the problem? Let me  assume that the previous execution was cached, somewhere I have no idea. Every time I compile the whole document, it is re-executed and modify all the files content right? If my understanding is correct, then why this problem occur. I would be glad if you can answer this or maybe post this as an answer. Appreciate u r time. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to ask an expert, and I'm far from that! I ALWAYS delete all temporary files before compiling a document from scratch (though not, of course, after the first or subsequent runs of a multiple run compilation).

Comment: @Sangamesh I'm not sure what you are after. Deleting all auxiliary files is the first thing every TeXnician does if he has any problem with any input file. So I lose your point. Deleting these files helped and you should be fine with iit.

Comment: @Sangamesh  For me, deleting those auxiliary files didn't help. Mark's answer below also didn't work. Your question was 5 years ago. Is there any update?

Comment: Oh problem fixed. It was because of ’   I have to use ' instead of ’ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, more a means of tracking down the problem. I have also had problems with undefined Unicode characters, so I add the following to my preambles:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar} 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFD}{?????}
```

The character FFFD is the Unicode replacement character. It enables a document to compile to completion and substitutes any undefined Unicode character with `?????' – which is fairly easy to track down.

Once you've established which character is causing the problem, you can define a new Unicode character (for example) as follows:

```
\newunicodechar{–}{--}
```

Comment: Really helpful package! For me the FFFD did not work since the error was ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char Ì (U+301). However, using '\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{301}{ HERE I AM!!!!! }' did the trick.

Comment: As I understand your answer, your code lines should replace undefined characters, but I still get an error:"package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined (inputenc) in input encoding 'utf8'". even if I use your lines in my preamble, what am I doing wrong? 
bevor your lines I write:
'\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}'
If you have a quick idea that would be great, otherwise I will have to open a new question with MWE...

Comment: For me, deleting those auxiliary files didn't help. And somehow adding the two lines ou suggested adding didn't create any "?????" although there do exist unicode characters. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Oh problem fixed. It was because of ’   I have to use ' instead of ’ .